# Golang cant get body from request.GetBody()

Tags: go

I try to read the request body via request.GetBody(), since I need to read the same request body more than once, but I always get the error below. I checked if the req.body is empty, but it is not. I cant even call req.GetBody(). My Go version is 1.8.1.

```
 func read(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

     _, err := req.GetBody()
    if err != nil {
        res.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }

}
```

Error:

```
http: panic serving [::1]:53174: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `GetBody()` func on `Request` is only for client requests (see the documentation over the `GetBody` member: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request), but it looks like you're doing a server-side handler. Therefore, you need to use the `req.Body` member, which is an `io.ReadCloser`. To read from an `io.ReadCloser` you can use the `io/ioutil` package and the `ReadAll()` func:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%s", b)
```

More information on the `ReadAll()` func: https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#example_ReadAll

Comment: Ahh ok thank, this means, I have to write my own server side GetBody() if I want to read the body multiple times while passing the request through a chain of middleware handlers, or is there a better solution ?

Comment: Yes, you can do your own implementation—or use a context (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context and https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.WithContext) to pass the information along the chain—if you use a context I would consider the `WithValue` option—appending the `[]byte` to a well known key.

Comment: Thank you PaulJ ! I will have a look at both options :)

Answer (score -12):

That means your `req` variable is `nil`.